# In excel Ignore Just last char while using match function

Tags: excel

I have a part# "U123A" and I am matching this no. with a vendors list, who's part no. is Illustrated "U123". I would Like to know if there is a way to ignore the last char. So, if the last char is "A" or "B" or "C"..... just ignore it...

```
=MATCH(F1,$A$1:$A$20,0) 

F1 = "U123A" ----
$A$1:$A$20 ("U123", "U124", "U125"....)
```

Answer (score 1):

To strip off the last character, you can try:

```
=MATCH(REPLACE(F1,LEN(F1),1,""),$A$1:$A$20,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`=MATCH(LEFT(F1, 4),$A$1:$A$20,0)`

Comment: Thank you very much. 
That would work in this example but in my original data, I have 5 chars or 7 chars in some places. How would I be able to tackle that Issue?

Comment: @user3118664 you can try `=MATCH(LEFT(F1, LEN(F1)-1),$A$1:$A$20,0)`

Comment: Ash's solution is best - removes the last character from the string.

Comment: THANK YOU A.S.H that really helps